# Warning, when you run same installer twice (WIX)

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

How I can perform showing message, that'll tell to user >>This version has already installed<< or some another warning message, when user try to run the same installer twice?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice for Windows Installer in the case of running the exact same installer twice is to present the user with a maintenance experience.   Here the user can Add/Remove features, perform a Repair or perform an Uninstall.

Comment: In general, I need some way to prevent running the exact same installer twice. First of all, I thought that I could use Upgrade Table for this task or Launch Condition. But every time, when I run the same installer, I don't receive any warning =(

Comment: Then you probably just want to modify your "Maintenance" dialog to display a message this this isn't supported and quit the installer. The maintenance dialog typically has a conditional expression of: Installed And Not RESUME and Not Preselected and Not PATCH